# Data hashing in Pentaho

Tags: postgresql, hash, pentaho, kettle

Can anyone suggest me the best possible options that I can use in  **pentaho** to suit my requirement. The requirement is we need to convert first_name & last_name attributes into hash and load the hash values for these columns into the user table to support the business reports. For the reports the actual values for these columns are not needed, the reporting code only checks for NULL values in first_name & last_name columns, and validates length of these fields.

I tried converting the fields to hash using Add checksum transformation but wasn't sure about which type of checksum to use (CRC 32, ADLER 32, MD5, SHA-1). Any suggestions?

**source & target DB is PostgreSql** not sure if it's needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do the reports use the hash values? How bad is it if you get a collision?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the access to reports and I am not aware about how the reports validate these hash values.

Comment: To be true not all that familiar with the concept of "hashing".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hashing and encryption are not the same thing.

It seems you want a one-way hash. What hash you choose depends mainly on how much you care about collisions. If you don't care that multiple names could generate the same hash, a short fast hash like CRC32 is fine. If you do care about collisions then I'd use at least MD5.